# Show a title in nano text editor

Tags: terminal, nano

I'm doing some setup script and I want to open the `nano` editor. In addition I want to show a title (or a TODO message) on the as a title in the terminal.

Something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please check the sql connection settings and save the file |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Standard nano content ...                                  |
|                                                            |
|                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Standard nano Footer                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this possible with nano?

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible to do this using a workaround. If you name your file “Please check the SQL connection settings and save the file”, `nano` will show that in the title:

[image: Screenshot of nano showing the file name “Please check the SQL connection settings and save the file” in reverse video on the top line]

You can set this up either using a symbolic link, or by renaming the file before and after running `nano`.